# Retrieving attributes from a resource group with a tempate composition

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I want to create multiple copies of some resources defined in a template. How do I retrieve the attributes of the resources created in this fashion.

To illustrate, here is a template to create a random string (I call `word.yaml`):

```yaml
heat_template_version: rocky

resources:
  word:
    type: OS::Heat::RandomString
```

Because I want a list of such random strings, I use an `OS::Heat::ResourceGroup` calling the template from word.yaml:

```yaml
heat_template_version: rocky

resources:
  composition:
    type: OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
    properties:
      count: 2
      resource_def:
        type: word.yaml

outputs:
  composition:
    value: {get_attr: [composition, resource.word]}
```

Rubbing together the explanation of `OS::Heat::ResourceGroup` ([ResourceGroup](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Heat::ResourceGroup)) and the template composition documentation ([nested attributes](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/composition.html#get-access-to-nested-attributes)), I expected a list of strings in my output, yet I get:

```json
{
  "outputs": [
    {
      "output_key": "composition",
      "description": "No description given",
      "output_error": "Member 'word' not found in group resource 'composition'.",
      "output_value": null
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing about the interaction of the resource group and the template composition?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: I need to specify the attribute to retrieve as outpus of the composition. So the `word.yaml` would look like this:

```yaml
heat_template_version: rocky

resources:
  word:
    type: OS::Heat::RandomString
outputs:
  word:
    description: the word
    value: {get_attr: [word]}
```

And the composition, like so:

```yaml
heat_template_version: rocky

resources:
  composition:
    type: OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
    properties:
      count: 2
      resource_def:
        type: word.yaml

outputs:
  composition:
    value: {get_attr: [composition, word]}
```

Yielding the expected output:

```json
  {
    "output_key": "composition",
    "description": "No description given",
    "output_value": [
      {
        "value": "gB7ZcXgNjJlEtf8N47yFCOQyH0a1bb9c"
      },
      {
        "value": "wXN4jAKgPqbf5i3GDR6qMkzfC7jF0xdC"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could give more than one +1